# Python itertools cycle function in Java

Tags: java, loops

Python has the itertools library which allows to loop a list of items infinitely.

```
cycle('ABCD') --> A B C D A B C D ...
```

How to achieve the same in java but for an array? for example:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
cycle(a) = 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 ....
```

Answer (score 5):

If using guava is an option it already has that with :

```
 Iterables.cycle
```

Comment: This won't work (by itself) for primitive arrays, but you can e.g. use `Ints.asList` to turn an `int[]` into a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman yup, I am aware of that. I just wrote a fast answer.. thx though!

Comment: @LouisWasserman o darn! You are the creator of guava! :) Yes, sensei!

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
public void cycle( int[] a ) {
    while ( true ) {
        for ( int val : a ) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And make it useful with a callback:

```
public interface Callback<T> {
    public void execute( T value );
}

public <T> void cycle( T[] a, Callback<T> callback ) {
    while ( true ) {
        for ( T val : a ) {
            callback.execute( val );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting you could also make an iterator like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Integer[] A = new Integer[]{1,2,3};
 CyclicArrayIterator<Integer> iter = new CyclicArrayIterator<>(A);
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    System.out.println(iter.next());
  }
}
```

Guava's method seems cleanest but if you don't want to include any dependencies. Here is the CyclicIterator class which you can use.

```
/**
 * An iterator to loop over an array infinitely.
 */
 public class CyclicArrayIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

   private final T[] A;
   private int next_index = 0;

   public CyclicArrayIterator(T[] array){
     this.A = array;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean hasNext() {
     return A[next_index] != null;
   }

   @Override
   public T next() {
     T t = A[next_index % A.length];
     next_index = (next_index + 1) % A.length;
     return t;
   }

   @Override
   public void remove() {
     throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
   }

 }
```

Hope it helps.